# Suppress all typesetting within a group

Tags: macros, spacing, grouping

I have a macro that is purely functional (e.g. only defines other macros), and I want to be able to invoke this inline without any new paragraphs or blank spaces being typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\test{
  \gdef\a{1}

  \gdef\b{1}
}

Hello {\test} world!
\end{document}
```

[image: output_1]

[Following this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16460/how-to-disable-new-paragraph-at-empty-line), I was able to remove all `\par`s generated by blank lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\test{
  \gdef\a{1}

  \gdef\b{1}
}

Hello {\let\par\relax\test} world!
\end{document}
```

[image: output_2]

However, this results in a few spaces where the macro is called.

Is there a way to, more generally, suppress all typesetting within a group?

If not, is there a way to suppress all spaces within a group as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(`\a` and `\b` are already defined by the LaTeX-kernel. Better not to override these definitions. Therefore in the example below I used `\A` and `\B` instead.)*

You can

- switch to `\nullfont` for neutralizing the typesetting of character-tokens
- redefine `\par` to do nothing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\bspesphackgroup[1]{\@bsphack{\nullfont\let\par=\empty#1}\@esphack}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\test{
  \gdef\A{1}

  \gdef\B{1}
}

Hello World!

Hello \bspesphackgroup{\test} World!
\end{document}
```

[image]

**But this will not prevent tpesetting in general.**

**E.g., a `\kern` or `\vskip` or `\hskip` or `\hrule` or `\vrule` will be carried out and have a visible effect. Besides this font-switching-commands inside `\test` may override `\nullfont`:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\bspesphackgroup[1]{\@bsphack{\nullfont\let\par=\empty#1}\@esphack}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\test{
  \gdef\A{1}

  \gdef\B{1}

  \let\par=\endgraf
  \par\vskip 2cm

  \leavevmode\vrule width 2cm height 2cm\relax

  \normalfont This is disturbing!

}

Hello World!

Hello \bspesphackgroup{\test} World!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't add spaces in your `\test` macro.

```
% nullprob.tex  SE 561601
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\test{%
  \gdef\a{1}%
%
  \gdef\b{1}%
}

Hello {\test}world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would work, but I'm keeping my `\def`s in an external file which I `\input`. It would be pretty inconvenient to have to do this on every line.

Answer (score 1):

*(`\a` and `\b` are already defined by the LaTeX-kernel. Better not to override these definitions. Therefore in the example below I used `\A` and `\B` instead.)*

The problem seems to be that within the *⟨definition text⟩* of `\test` control-word-tokens `\par` and space-tokens come into being in places where they should not come into being.

**In case the definitions nested inside the definiton of `\test` (i.e., the definition of `\A` and the definition of `\B`) don't contain linebreaks that should yield space-tokens or `\par`-tokens** you can temporarily have `\endlinechar` denote the `%`-character which has category-code 14 (comment) instead of having it denote the return-character which has category code 5 (end of line) and therefore—depending on the state of TeX's reading apparatus—either yields no token at all or yields a space-token or yields the control-word-token `\par`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\endlinechar=`\%\relax
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup
  \def\test{
    \def\A{1}

    \def\B{1}
  }
}

\show\test

\begin{document}
Hello world!

\show\A
\show\B

Hello \test world!

\show\A
\show\B
\end{document}
```

[image]

The console-output reveals that in the *⟨definition text⟩* of `\test` there are neither `\par`-tokens nor space-tokens between/behind the *⟨definition texts⟩* of `\A` and `\B`:

```
> \test=macro:
->\def \A {1}\def \B {1}.
l.15 \show\test
               
? 
(./test.aux)
> \A=undefined.
l.20 \show\A
            
? 
> \B=undefined.
l.21 \show\B
            
? 
> \A=macro:
->1.
l.25 \show\A
            
? 
> \B=macro:
->1.
l.26 \show\B
            
?
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to effectively disable spaces, referencing page 76 of the TeXbook.

I did this by setting `\spacefactor=10000` and `\xspaceskip=0.0001pt` for a fixed-width negligible space, and removing the space after my grouping.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\test{
  \gdef\a{1}

  \gdef\b{1}
}

Hello {\spacefactor=10000\xspaceskip=0.0001pt\let\par\relax\test}world!
\end{document}
```

[image: output_1]

This does seem like a bit of a workaround, so if anyone knows of a better solution please let me know!

Edit:

I created the macros `\bnosp` and `\enosp` that allow me to truly embed such a macro inline, without the need for `\gdef`. `\bnosp` saves the value of `\spacefactor`, `\xspaceskip` and `\par` before changing them to the values above and invoking the macro, then `\enosp` resets them to their original values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\test{
  \def\a{1}

  \def\b{1}
}

\def\bnosp{\edef\xspaceskiporig{\the\xspaceskip}\edef\spacefactororig{\the\spacefactor}\let\parorig\par\spacefactor=10000\xspaceskip=0.00001pt\let\par\relax}
\def\enosp{\spacefactor=\spacefactororig\xspaceskip=\xspaceskiporig\let\par\parorig}

Hello \bnosp \test \enosp world! 

\a\ \b
\end{document}
```

[image: output_2]

Comment: \sbox0{\test} should work

Comment: Yes, this is almost exactly what I wanted, thank you! However, if I were to replace my `\gdef`s with `\def`s, they wouldn't be defined outside the grouping. Do you know of a way to resolve this?

Comment: that is true of any group not just the box suggestion. so it is by design not a problem to be solved?  you do not have to have a group but this question asks about the case with a group??

Comment: Yes, my bad, you've answered my question as asked. I'll look into this as a separate question.

Comment: (see recent edit)